# Why does NWPathMonitor not give a path update when the path becomes satisfied?

Tags: swift, nwpathmonitor

I have a simple class named **NetworkPathMonitor** that looks as follows:

```
class NetworkPathMonitor: ObservableObject, Cancellable {
    @Published var path: NWPath? = nil
    
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.path = path
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        monitor.cancel()
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Although `pathUpdateHandler` is called when I disable and enable WiFi the outcome is not always reliable. When I disable the WiFi the current path is `unsatisfied (No network route)`, however when I enable WiFi again it calls `pathUpdateHandler` again with the same path `unsatisfied (No network route)`.

However in my UI I have a button that says Retry. When I press it, it will destroy the current monitor and build a new one. The first message now says `satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0`. Meaning, perhaps it took some time for the WiFi to establish the network route but when the network did become available it did not call `pathUpdateHandler` again.

Answer (score 10):

The code **did** work on a real device.

Do not test `NWPathMonitor` on an iOS Simulator, because it will not give you a reliable result.